# Confused about Google Cloud Platform committed use discount plans

Tags: google-cloud-platform

If I buy committment for 4 vCPUS and 26 GB of RAM, the GCP pricing calculator says my monthly estimated bill would be around $ 166 for 730 hours a month. What if I use only 10 hours a month? Do I have to pay $ 166 or will I billed for 10 hours only?

Someone please explain.

Answer (score 1):

I understand by commitment you are referring to *"Committed Use Discounts"*. Thus, as [mentioned in this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts), once purchased; you will be billed a monthly fee for the duration of the term you selected ***whether or not you use the service***. So, the amount of uptime will not change anything in the price as this specific contract is deeply discounted.

Comment: The same document has given an example scenario of billing in which it shows that the customer has purchased committment for 360 hours a month and not 730, but when I go to purchasing committment page, I dont see any option to select number of hours.

Comment: @Naveed, I believe you are referring to the [example given here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#understanding_your_bill_with_committed_use_discounts). I suppose here the calculation is done from June 1, 2017, to June 15, 2017, making it **15 days** and `15 X 24= 360 hours of usage` rather than a whole month.